# How to find the mean for all the columns with one condition for columns with text

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
Class   Identifier  Configuration   1               2   3   4   5   6   7   8
plugins 80ec584f    Def1            0.5269079614    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.5269079614
plugins 80ec584f    Def1            0.0980391133    0.0980391133    0.2269675225    0.2269675225    0.2269675225            0.2269675225    0.2269675225    0.2269675225
plugins 80ec584f    Def1            0.0980391133    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0980391133
plugins 80ec584f    Def1            0.5269079614    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.5269079614
plugins 80ec584f    Def1            0.0980391133    0.0980391133    0.2269675225    0.2269675225    0.2269675225            0.2269675225    0.2269675225    0.2269675225
plugins 80ec584f    Def1            0.0980391133    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0980391133
```

I would like to get the mean of each column such that:

```
Class   Identifier  Configuration   1           2               3               4   5   6   7   8
plugins 80ec584f    Def1            0.240995396 0.0326797044    0.0756558408    0.0756558408    0.0756558408    0.0756558408    0.0756558408    0.2839715324
```

The outcome I expect is the first three columns should be as they are and the other columns must return the mean values.

I used something like `colMeans(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)])` but this only returns the mean of columns 1 - 8 but the first three columns are not shown.

Can you please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could group by first 3 columns and then take `mean` of remaining columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Class, Identifier, Configuration) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = mean))

# Class   Identifier Configuration    X1     X2     X3     X4     X5     X6     X7    X8
#  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 plugins 80ec584f   Def1          0.241 0.0327 0.0757 0.0757 0.0757 0.0757 0.0757 0.284
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax to find mean might help you where `numeric_only = None` is applied.

```
DataFrame.mean(axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None, **kwargs)
```

Comment: @AdamAmin Because `**kwargs` in function definitions in python is used to pass a keyworded, variable-length argument list and not the `**kwargs` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge them back together after you computed the mean:

```
means <- colMeans(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)])
output <- cbind(df[1, 1:3], means)
```

Comment: This shows the mean of the 8 columns in one column. Each column mean must be in one column (look at the expected outcome)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `aggregate`, e.g.,

```
aggregate(.~Class + Identifier + Configuration, df, mean)
```

which gives

```
> aggregate(.~Class + Identifier + Configuration, df, mean)
    Class Identifier Configuration         1         2          3          4
1 plugins   80ec584f          Def1 0.2409954 0.0326797 0.07565584 0.07565584
           5          6          7         8
1 0.07565584 0.07565584 0.07565584 0.2839715
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Class = c("plugins", "plugins", "plugins", "plugins", 
"plugins", "plugins"), Identifier = c("80ec584f", "80ec584f",
"80ec584f", "80ec584f", "80ec584f", "80ec584f"), Configuration = c("Def1",
"Def1", "Def1", "Def1", "Def1", "Def1"), `1` = c(0.5269079614, 
0.0980391133, 0.0980391133, 0.5269079614, 0.0980391133, 0.0980391133
), `2` = c(0, 0.0980391133, 0, 0, 0.0980391133, 0), `3` = c(0,
0.2269675225, 0, 0, 0.2269675225, 0), `4` = c(0, 0.2269675225,
0, 0, 0.2269675225, 0), `5` = c(0, 0.2269675225, 0, 0, 0.2269675225, 
0), `6` = c(0, 0.2269675225, 0, 0, 0.2269675225, 0), `7` = c(0,
0.2269675225, 0, 0, 0.2269675225, 0), `8` = c(0.5269079614, 0.2269675225,
0.0980391133, 0.5269079614, 0.2269675225, 0.0980391133)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```

Comment: Got this error `Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : no rows to aggregate`

Comment: @AdamAmin Did you try the data in my answer? It didn't give any error.

Comment: @AdamAmin Could you use `dput(df)` and paste the data to your post?

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = .(Class, Identifier, Configuration)]
#     Class Identifier Configuration         1         2          3          4          5          6          7         8
#1: plugins   80ec584f          Def1 0.2409954 0.0326797 0.07565584 0.07565584 0.07565584 0.07565584 0.07565584 0.2839715
```